# Sending data in socket server using C

Tags: c

I am beginner in networking and trying to learn writing simple server. I've tried writing a simple socket server using linux manual commands. I have couple of questions.
Is it possible to send data as a client to a server, and then pass the data from server to client again? Also, whenever I run my server, I am getting this weird message not sure why.
[image]

Also, what could I improve in my code?

Server:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int socket_serv;
    char response[256] = "Connected to server";
    socket_serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socket_serv == -1) {
        perror("Error connecting to server");
    }
    struct sockaddr_in socket_addr;
    socket_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    socket_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(socket_serv, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_addr, sizeof(socket_addr));
    listen(socket_serv, 50);
    accept(socket_serv, NULL, NULL);
    
    send(socket_serv, response, sizeof(response), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int socket_serv;
    socket_serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in socket_addr;
    
    socket_addr.sin_family = AF_INET,
    socket_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    socket_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int status  = connect(socket_serv, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_addr, sizeof(socket_addr));
    if(status == -1) {
        perror("cant connect");
    }
    char server_res[256];
    recv(socket_serv, &server_res, sizeof(server_res), 0);

    printf("Data from server: %s", server_res);

    close(socket_serv);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `accept(socket_serv, NULL, NULL);` accept returns a (new) filedescriptor. Use it! `recv(socket_serv, server_res, sizeof(server_res), 0);` recv() returns the number of actually recieved bytes. Use it!

Comment: In addition, you should be checking the return value of *all* the function calls. The code should not be blinding proceeding without knowing whether each call has succeeded or not.

Comment: You should probably take a few steps back and get a solid grasp of pointers and memory management in C before trying to do anything with sockets.

Comment: (what is `sizeof(response)` in the server code? Where is the client supposed to store read data?)

Comment: @Shawn I've edited my code, now I am getting an empty value in response

Comment: And how about the `accept`? Calling `send` with `socket_serv` is completely wrong and must be changed before that has any chance of working. You need to send to the socket returned by `accept`.

Comment: @kaylum, thanks that fixed the issue

Comment: You should exit(EXIT_FAILURE) after perror().

Comment: For all things network, see [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) (contains examples and tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the server the `accept` function should be in the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int socket_serv;
    char response[256] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Length: 20\n\nConnected to server\n";
    socket_serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socket_serv == -1) {
        perror("Error connecting to server");
    }
    struct sockaddr_in socket_addr;
    socket_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    socket_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(socket_serv, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_addr, sizeof(socket_addr));
    listen(socket_serv, 50);

    for (;;) {
        int fd = accept(socket_serv, NULL, NULL);
        printf("accepted socket: %d\n", fd);
       
        // read request
        char rbuf[512];
        read(fd, rbuf, 512);
        printf("%s", rbuf);
        
        // send response
        send(fd, response, strlen(response), 0);
        close(fd);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The loop accepts and processes new connections. Note that `send` sends strlen(response) bytes, not all 256 bytes.

I put one single `read` here. Ideally `read` should be in the loop to read all arrived packets.

Test it with `curl -v 127.0.0.1:8080`